# How to delete an entity from a datastore, using java datastore.delete(key)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've been trying to delete an entity for 2 nights now, without success.  And I'm sure my problem is simple for many of you.

I successfully put() an entity using User.getNickName() as key:

```
 Key aKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Gamer2", user.getNickname()); 
 Entity aGamer = new Entity("Gamer2", aKey);
 aGamer.setProperty("nickName", user.getNickname());
 DatastoreService aDS = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
 aDS.put(aGamer);
```

But I can't figure out how to do the delete.

Any help is appreciated.  Please also let me know if my question has incomplete info.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you delete it:

```
DatastoreService aDS = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

Key aKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Gamer2", user.getNickname());
aDS.delete(aKey);
```

Also, you don't need to set the property "nickName", because you already used it to create your key. When you need to get the nickname, you do:

```
user.setNickname(entity.getKey().getName());
```

UPDATE:

There is a problem in how you create your entity. Do it this way:

```
Entity entity = new Entity("Gamer2", user.getNickname());
aDS.put(entity);
```

Comment: Andrei - thank you for taking the time to reply. It's still not working for me though.  And I don't get any java error message either.  Will it help if I add the following Datastore data? Decoded entity key: Gamer2: name=karaoke.night.100 > Gamer2: id=5741031244955648
Entity key: ahRzfmdhbWVvZnRoZWdlbmVyYWxzMnIwCxIGR2FtZXIyIhFrYXJhb2tlLm5pZ2h0LjEwMAwLEgZHYW1lcjIYgICAgICumQoM

Comment: Awesome! It finally worked!  Thanks Andrei.  Really appreciate that.

Comment: Then you should accept the answer - this is how StackOverflow works. I hope you will enjoy it!